# How to sort numbers in python by number?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list like this:

```
listA = ['Word1_4', 'Word2_2', 'Word3_1', 'Word4_3']
```

Into a list like this:

```
listB = ['Word3_1', 'Word2_2', 'Word4_3', 'Word1_4']
```

I would enter some code that I've already written but I'm unfamiliar with python and I have no idea for a solution.

Thanks - Wastive

Comment: Please update your question with *some* code which attempts a sort, just to explain why it doesn't produce the required output.

Comment: As I said, I have no idea how to do this. I could probably make some monstrosity thats hundreds of lines long, but I know that there's someone with more experience than me who can show me how to do it simpler and cleaner.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to search stackoverflow for some ideas about sorting. (*hint: sorted() is a built-in function*)

Comment: `listA.sort(key=lambda s: s[-1])` will be the simplest thing i can find. But it may be not the fastest one. If you don't mind of memory usage you can implement [Radix Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) (as it will be the fastest one) on your own.

Comment: Which part of the words are used for sorting? Can these numbers be multiple digits? If so, do you want them sorted lexicographically? Would "Word5_22" come before or after "Word5_100"?

Answer (score 1):

Lists have a built-in function named `sort` that can do the trick. But, make sure to assign a key argument to this function in order to sort the list based on the last character:

```py
listA = ['Word1_4', 'Word2_2', 'Word3_1', 'Word4_3']
listA.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])
listA
```

##### Output

```
['Word3_1', 'Word2_2', 'Word4_3', 'Word1_4']
```

##### Modified

without converting the digits to int you would be sorting based on string values(Thanks to @Ade_1 for the edit).

```
sorter = lambda x: int(x.split('_')[-1]) 
listA.sort(key=sorter)
print(listA)
```

Comment: Thanks! If it doesn't take too much time, what does 'key=lambda' mean?

Comment: That's what I meant about doing some searches on Stackoverflow. All the information is there.

Comment: @wastive `key=` is a named argument of function `list.sort`. This argument is a bit special because it must be a function, rather than an int or a string or some other type. You can either use a function that is already defined, or a function that you previously defined yourself using `def`, or you can define a nameless inline function using `lambda`.

Comment: @wastive Also note it's not just `key=lambda`, but rather `listA.sort(key= (lambda x: x[-1]) )`

Comment: @wastive See also the official python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions

Comment: I would suggest using `x.rsplit('_', maxsplit=1)[-1]` rather than `x.split('_')[-1]`.